# How do i send image in php cUrl to api

Tags: php, wordpress, api, curl, file-upload

I'm trying to create a wordpress php connction to a stable diffusion model on replicate.com. It seems to work but when i'm adding an init image the processing won't start. Actually it halts on "status: starting" with no output prompts. I can see the image on my api prediction on the replicate Dashboard, but i think the image isn't really uploaded. When i click "Tweek" and replaces the image it works.
What am i doing wrong here?

```
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions');
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$data = array(
   'version' => '56f26876a159c10b429c382f66ccda648c1d5678d7ce15ed010734b715be5ab9', 
   'input' => array(
        'prompt' => 'circles',
        'init_image' => 'https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/img.jpg'
    )
);
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Token njdscknjk3nkjn32nk3jn3j';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curl_exec($resource);
```

Comment: Make sure the API can access your image URL. Even when you can access the URL, the API may not. You could change it to [a data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs), using Base64.

Comment: @Phil  That was brilliant, closing a question and referring to a closed question.

Comment: @Misunderstood I've re-opened. Turns out the API expects URL strings. In any case, even if a post is closed, as long as it has answers it's a valid duplicate target

Comment: I was referring to the irony, not if it's proper.  I was not dissing you.  And the API also requires `Content-Type: application/json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You curl is doing what you are asking it to do.
This is what the server will see:

```
Content-Length: 174
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
BODY=
{"version":"56f26876a159c10b429c382f66ccda648c1d5678d7ce15ed010734b715be5ab9","input":{"prompt":"circles","init_image":"https:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/img.jpg"}}
```

You are transmitting the image url rather than the image.  Try this:

```
$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents('https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/img.jpg'));

'init_image' => $image;
```

The image may also need to be prefixed by: `'data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>'`

```
$image = 'data: image/jpeg;base64,' .  base64_encode(file_get_contents('https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/img.jpg'));
```

And the base64 data may (or may not) need to be URL encoded with PHP's `urlencode()` function.

You are doing an HTTPS post so you may (or may not) need these but the request would not be secure and the server would likely reject it.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Comment: The API expects an HTTP or data URL so you should prefix `$image` with `data:image/jpg;base64,`

Comment: @Phil  I swear I did not see your comment until after I saved my edits.  I was editing when you posted your comment.

Comment: Wish I could upvote twice 

Comment: Thanks @Misunderstood, it works! You have saved my day :-) The extra curl_setopt wasn't necessary.